# How to create Url that contain name and id laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a product url have id and name like, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/23/walking shoes`. Previously the url was showing only the product id, I have tried to follow some sources online and I'm stuck with this error `A non-numeric value encountered` how can I make the url contains both product id and name?

```
 <a href="{{url('productDetail',$product->id/$product->pro_name)}}">
```

Route

```
   Route::get('/productDetail/{id}/{pro_name}', 
  'HomeController@detailPro');
```

Controller

```
   public function shop()
   {
    $products=product::with('ProductsPhoto')->paginate(2);
    return view('front.shop',compact('products'));
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the two methods

```
<a href="{{ url('productDetail',[$product->id, $product->pro_name]) }}">
```

Or

```
<a href="{{ url('productDetail/ ' . $product->id . '/' . $product->pro_name .') }}">
```

Comment: Your answer and Rouhollah answer both works fine but I want to remove `%20`. Now the url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/40/walking%20shoes` , how can I make it like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/40/walking shoes` @Zahid hasan emon

Comment: well you can't use a space in a url. as your product name has  a space it is being replaced by `%20`

Comment: So is there any way may be I can replace with `-` so it can be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/40/walking-shoe` @zahid hasan

Comment: yes. you can use `str_slug` like `<a href="{{ url('productDetail',[$product->id, str_slug($product->pro_name)]) }}">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{url('productDetail'),['id'=>$product->id, 'pro_name'=>$product->pro_name]}}">
```

Comment: You misplaced the `)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the url looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/40/walking%20shoes` is there any way to remove the '%20` so the url can be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/productDetail/40/walkingshoes`  @Rouhollah Mazarei